# Test angular 6 service methods with jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular6

how are you?

I`ve developed a login service in angular 6 that depends on Http and ConfigService, and need to test its methods. How do I do this with jasmine?

Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

For the HTTP part of the service [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests) might help you out.

As for the ConfigService, if it has external dependencies injecting it in your test files will throw errors unless there are providers for said dependencies. In these situations it's best to make a stub of the service (ConfigService in this case) and inject that in your login service in place of the real thing. Otherwise, inject the real service and spy on its methods.